# without declaration the function first, I can swap the value of the variables?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void swap(int, int);

int main()
{
    int a=10;
    int b=20;

    swap (a, b);

    cout << "a: " << a << endl;
    cout << "b: " << b << endl;

    return 0;
}

void swap(int x, int y)
{
    int t;
    t = x;
    x = y;
    y = t;
}
```

---

those code above can't swap the value of a and b.
but my question is , when I forgot to type the third line "void swap(int, int);
" , the values of a and b swaped !! why?

Answer (score 7):

It's because you have

```
using namespace std;
```

At the beginning of your source code.

This is a [a bad programming practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice), whose consequences you just experienced, first hand. You told the compiler that you want to invoke `std::swap`, without having any clue that you actually did that.

It's ironical, because you version of swap() won't work right, but `std::swap` does; so you were operating under the mistaken impression that your code was working, when it didn't.

Never use "using namespace std;" with your code. Simply forget that this part of the C++ language ever existed.

Comment: If the function prototype is written just before the function declaration it works what difference does it make?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    cout << "a: " << a << endl;
    cout << "b: " << b << endl;
    system("pause");
    swap(a, b);

    cout << "a: " << a << endl;
    cout << "b: " << b << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

void swap is unnecessary

Answer (score -1):

If you put the function definition above main then you don't need a prototype otherwise you do need it and the compiler should give you an error if you don't have a prototype